# Typescript Eslint strict boolean expressions error in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, eslint

i have an error in my code but i can't solve the problem.

My type definition is like this :

```
interface MealType {
  id: number
  name: string
  ingredients: [
    {
      name: string
      quantity: number
      quantity_type: string
    }
  ]
}

interface IngredientsType {
  name: string
  groups: ['vegan' | 'vegetarian'] | undefined
  options: [
    {
      name: string
      quality: 'high' | 'medium' | 'low'
      price: number
      per_amount: 'kilogram' | 'litre'
    }
  ]
}
```

My full component :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import type { MealType, IngredientsType } from '../../types/global'
import ListItem from './ListItem'
import styles from './MobileMealList.module.scss'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import classNames from '../../util/classNames'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { getQuery } from '../../../app/api/API'

const MobileMealList = ({ meals }: { meals: MealType[] }): JSX.Element => {
  const [sortedMeals, setSortedMeals] = useState<MealType[]>(meals)
  const [sortType, setSortType] = useState<'all' | 'name'>('all')
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<'all' | 'vegan' | 'vegetarian'>('all')

  const { data: ingredients } = useQuery<IngredientsType[]>('ingredients', {
    queryFn: async () => await getQuery('/listIngredients'),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ingredients === undefined) return

    let sortFn
    let filterFn

    if (sortType === 'all') {
      sortFn = (a: MealType, b: MealType) => {
        return 0
      }
    } else if (sortType === 'name') {
      sortFn = (a: MealType, b: MealType) => {
        if (a.name < b.name) {
          return -1
        }
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return 1
        }
        return 0
      }
    }

    if (filter === 'vegan') {
      filterFn = (meal: MealType) => {
        let vegan = true
        meal.ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
          const ingredientFull = ingredients.find((i) => i.name === ingredient.name)
          if (ingredientFull === undefined || ingredientFull.groups === undefined) {
            return
          }
          if (
            !ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegan') ||
            ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegetarian')
          ) {
            vegan = false
          }
        })
        return vegan
      }
    } else if (filter === 'vegetarian') {
      filterFn = (meal: MealType) => {
        let vegetarian = true
        meal.ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
          const ingredientFull = ingredients.find((i) => i.name === ingredient.name)
          if (ingredientFull === undefined || ingredientFull.groups === undefined) {
            return
          }
          if (!ingredientFull.groups.includes('vegetarian')) {
            vegetarian = false
          }
        })
        return vegetarian
      }
    } else {
      filterFn = () => true
    }

    const sortedMeals = meals.filter(filterFn).sort(sortFn)
    setSortedMeals(sortedMeals)
  }, [sortType, meals])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ingredients', ingredients)
  }, [ingredients])
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="font-jost">
        <div>Showing all {meals.length} results.</div>
        <Form.Select
          className={classNames(styles.select, 'shadow-none')}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSortType(e.target.value as 'all' | 'name')
          }}
          value={sortType}>
          <option value="all">Default Sorting</option>
          <option value="name">Sort by name</option>
        </Form.Select>
        <Form.Select
          className={classNames(styles.select, 'shadow-none')}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFilter(e.target.value as 'all' | 'vegan' | 'vegetarian')
          }}
          value={filter}>
          <option value="all">All Types</option>
          <option value="vegan">Vegan</option>
          <option value="vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
        </Form.Select>
      </div>
      <div>
        {sortedMeals.map((meal) => (
          <ListItem key={meal.id} meal={meal} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MobileMealList
```

And it says :

Line 56:14:  Unexpected any value in conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast is required  @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

Line 57:13:  Unexpected any value in conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast is required  @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

Line 74:16:  Unexpected any value in conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast is required  @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

Line 56 and 57 are these lines :

```
 !ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegan') ||
            ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegetarian')
```

And line 74 is this line :

```
if (!ingredientFull.groups.includes('vegetarian')) {
```

I look at the code but cant find anything about `an any value in conditional`.

And the problem is in the terminal, IDE doesn't give an error to me, just terminal.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegetarian')` resolves to the a union `undefined | boolean`, you must cast it to a boolean using: `!!ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegetarian')`

Comment: you should first check if `groups` exists in your ingredientFull, then check if it includes vegetarian

Comment: I tried !!ingredientFull.groups?.includes('vegetarian') and it didn't work. Still gives the same error. @Chris

Comment: I also tried @JorgeGuerreiro's answer and it didn't work too, still gives same error.

Comment: something like `ingredientFull.groups && !ingredientFull.groups.includes('vegan')`

Comment: For `ingredientFull.groups &&`  it says `Unexpected object value in conditional. The condition is always true.` and previous error still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the interfaces. You've defined an Array of objects as `[{ name: string }]` in your interface. This strictly means that the **first** element of the array, should match the type given. E.g. it is not a list of objects, but a list with the first element being X. These types are called [Tuples](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-tuple) in TypeScript.

This is how you can define an Array with pairs like `[string, boolean]` for example.

In your case, you want to use the list of syntax instead:

```
interface MealType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ingredients: {
    name: string
    quantity: number
    quantity_type: string
  }[]; // <-- see here
}

interface IngredientsType {
  name: string;
  groups?: ('vegan' | 'vegetarian')[]; // <- array containing 'vegan' or 'vegetarian'
  options: {
    name: string
    quality: 'high' | 'medium' | 'low'
    price: number
    per_amount: 'kilogram' | 'litre'
  }[]; // <- see here
}
```